# Swift, for loop expression with map/high order function

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

Consider the following code:
Output is the result.

```
let array = [1, 5, 2]
var result = [Int]()
var stack = 0
array.forEach {
  result.append($0 + stack)
  stack += $0 + 1
}
```

Is there a way to write those with .map or other high order functions?

```
let result = array.map { 
  // fill this up plz
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output? `stack`? or `result`? or both?

Comment: @matt The result. The question is updated. Thanks

Comment: Even if you don’t care about `stack` you still need for it to persist through the loops. And the two solutions you’ve been shown are two ways to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be

```
let array = [1, 5, 2]
var stack = 0

let result: [Int] = array.map { 
    let res = $0 + stack
    stack += $0 + 1
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce(into:)`:

```
    let array = [1, 5, 2]
    let (stack,result) = array.reduce(into: (0,[Int]())) { (pair, i) in
        pair.1.append(i + pair.0)
        pair.0 += i + 1
    }
    print(stack)
    print(result)
```

(But note that the question is unclear. If one of `stack` and `result` was merely a scratch value and you don't need both of them as output, the above can be simplified considerably.)

Comment: Call me a heretic, but I think a map call with a side effect is much more readable, even if it does upset the pureness of the closure. It also has the benefit of calling reserveCapacity for you, which you forgot ;)

Comment: @Alexander I don't call you a heretic. I'm answering the question as I understand it, not saying that the goal of the question is good. I'm not even sure I know what the goal of the question _is_.

Comment: It's just tongue-in-cheek (I think, honestly I'm not sure what that means, lol). But yeah, I think I you got it, as far as I understand it. Although you're doing a COW copy on each step, you'll want to mutate the tuple element in-place.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, I was in some doubt as to whether the elements of the tuple would be mutable in place. Fixed.

Comment: It's mutable for `reduce(into:_:)` (where the param is `inout`). It's immutable for the regular old `reduce(_:_:)`

Comment: @Alexander `reduce(into:)` is not needed at all `let (stack,result) = array.reduce((0,[])) { ($0.0 + $1 + 1, $0.1 + CollectionOfOne($1 + $0.0)) }`

Comment: That incurs a COW copy on each iteration, leading to quadratic time complexity. Though I think it's a bit more clear